# nginx grpc_pass works only on root

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, grpc

This works:

```
server {
    listen 5005 http2;
    
    location / {
        grpc_pass grpc://my_app:5001;
    }

    default_type application/grpc;
}
```

this doesnt work:

```
server {
    listen 5005 http2;
    
    location /test {
        grpc_pass grpc://my_app:5001;
    }

    default_type application/grpc;
}
```

I receive logs when I go to localhost:5005, it looks like this:

```
192.168.0.1 - - [20/Sep/2021:10:18:02 +0000] "POST /tasks.TasksServiceGRPC/AskForJob HTTP/2.0" 200 153 "-" "grpc-node/1.24.7 grpc-c/8.0.0 (windows; chttp2; ganges)" "-"
```

When I go to localhost:5005/test, I'm not even getting the logs in nginx

on http 1.1 everything is working fine

Comment: Having a similar issue here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: It is not possible with grpc, because of request structure.

Comment: I see, thanks! If you answer your own question you can get some extra points if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with grpc, because of request structure

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should set the location value as the grpc URL to which the client is referring. For example, for me this was the case

```
location /App.ControlRoom.Api.Contract.ApiService/UpdateOpcDaTags {
        grpc_pass grpcs://cdpkat-dev_webuidev;
        }
```

For you i think like this:

```
server {
    listen 5005 http2;
    
    location /tasks.TasksServiceGRPC/AskForJob {
        grpc_pass grpc://my_app:5001;
    }

    default_type application/grpc;
}
```